# Can a victim of the Dream spell's nightmare take another long rest immediately after the rest they were affected by Dream?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, rests

The *Dream* spell states as part of its effect:

> You can make the messenger appear monstrous and terrifying to the target. If you do, the messenger can deliver a message of no more than ten words and then the target must make a Wisdom saving throw. On a failed save, echoes of the phantasmal monstrosity spawn a nightmare that lasts the Duration of the target's sleep **and prevents the target from gaining any benefit from that rest**. In addition, when the target wakes up, it takes 3d6 psychic damage. (PHB, page 236)

If the victim is affected by *Dream* during a long rest, they don't gain the benefit of the long rest upon waking from their sleep (for example, a cleric won't recover spent spell slots).

Does this effect interact at all with being unable to benefit from more than one long rest in a 24-hour period? Could the victim wake from their *Dream*'d long rest (gaining no benefits) and immediately attempt to take another long rest to actually gain the benefits?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes.

You can only gain the *benefits* of a long rest once per 24 hours. If you don't gain the *benefits* for any reason (if it is interrupted by more than an hour of strenuous activity or, say, a bad *Dream*) then you can start a new one right away and try to gain the benefits, assuming that you don't get interrupted again.

From the *Players Handbook*

> **Long Rest**
>
> A long rest is a **period of extended downtime, at least 8 hours long**, during which a character sleeps for at least 6 hours and performs no more than 2 hours of light activity, such as reading, talking, eating, or standing watch. [*note: this was errata'd in Sage Advice*] If the rest is interrupted by a period of strenuous activity–at least 1 hour of walking, fighting, casting spells, or similar adventuring activity–the characters must begin the rest again to gain any benefit from it.
>
> At the end of a long rest, a character regains all lost hit points. The character also regains spent Hit Dice, up to a number of dice equal to half of the character's total number of them (minimum of one die). For example, if a character has eight Hit Dice, he or she can regain four spent Hit Dice upon finishing a long rest.
>
> A character can't **benefit** from more than one long rest in a 24-hour period, and a character must have at least 1 hit point at the start of the rest to gain its benefits. (PHB, page 186)

Note that it does not specify *anywhere in the text including any errata changes* that the character can't try again should the first rest not grant its benefits, it *only* specifies that they cannot gain the benefits more than once per 24 hour period.

Comment: It may be worth stating that it is ultimately and entirely up to the GM whether a creature actually qualifies for a long rest regardless of whether they meet the requirements

Comment: @Medix2 Technically, everything you do in game ever is up to the GM. Generally speaking, reminding others of that is unhelpful.

Comment: Can you sleep for 8 hours, and then immediately sleep for another 8 hours? I can't.

Comment: @MarkWells *"A long rest is a period of extended downtime, at least 8 hours long, during which a character sleeps **or performs light activity: reading, talking, eating, or standing watch for no more than 2 hours."***

Comment: @RevenantBacon Just so we're clear, are you claiming that a long rest doesn't require sleeping at all? What exactly is the "no more than 2 hours" restriction, then?

Comment: @Mark (but mainly RevenantBavon) Please note that the PHB received errata and your quote is incorrect. It now reads: "A long rest is a period of extended downtime, at least 8 hours long, 
during which **a character sleeps for at 
least 6 hours** and performs no more than 
2 hours of light activity, such as reading, 
talking, eating, or standing watch."

Comment: @Medix2 Thank you for supplying the corrected version. So, again: If you sleep for 6-8 hours, and then wake up, can you immediately sleep for another 6-8 hours? (I can see a plausible argument that if you spent that time being tormented by nightmares so bad that you didn't get any rest, you might be ready to go right back to sleep, but that's not the argument being made here.)

Comment: @MarkWells That depends. If I sleep nice and sound without being disturbed, then no. On the other hand, if I'm constantly tossing from a *magically enhanced nightmare*, then yeah, I bet I could get some more sleep in. I mean, I could sleep for a solid 12 hours a day as it is, if I didn't ave to get up for work.

Comment: @Medix2 I always thought that the 2 hours referred to the standing watch part specifically. I will incorporate the Errata into my answer.